# Поставить другой класс у одного слова

Tags: html, css

помогите с проблемой. Нужно изменить класс у слова, но так, чтобы вся эта конструкция осталась одним целым предложением без переносов слова на другую строчку.

HTML:

`<div class = second_form_text> Привет,  <p class  = "form_inst">как дела  </p> </div>`

Comment: у какого слова из примера ты хочешь изменить класс?

Comment: У слова "Как дела "

Comment: Для этого в html есть куча строчных тегов с семантикой и бе http://htmlbook.ru/html/type/inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы не возникло лишнего "переноса", текст нужно оборачивать в элемент, у которого в стилях установлено

```
display: inline
```

либо

```
display: inline-block
```

По-умолчанию, такие настройки есть у элемента [`span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

```html
<div class=s econd_form_text> Привет, <span class="form_inst">как дела  </span> </div>
```

Также можно самостоятельно установить это свойство

```css
.form_inst {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="second_form_text"> Привет,
  <p class="form_inst">как дела </p>
</div>
<div class="second_form_text"> Привет,
  <p>как дела </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можем просто обернуть его в `<span></span>` и будет так например `<div class = second_form_text> Привет,  <p class  = "form_inst"><span class ="text"> как дела </span> </p> </div>` и уже с классом text работать